# Sending Standard Push Notifications to Newsstand Apps

Tags: objective-c, ios5, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com, newsstand-kit

How do you send standard push notifications to a Newsstand app? When I say "standard", I mean the typical alert box that pops up with the message.

I am using Urban Airship and have the "content-available" push working fine like so:

```
 {"aps": 
        {
         "content-available": 1
        }, 
         "device_tokens": ["1234ABCDKKGGOGOGG85986598750870870875708ASD"]
 }
```

But when I try to send a standard push, the alert never pops and my delegate

```
application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

is not called:

```
     {"aps": 
        {
         "alert": "Hi, from Urban Airship!"
        }, 
         "device_tokens": ["1234ABCDKKGGOGOGG85986598750870870875708ASD"]
 }
```

Comment: Down vote with no comment explaining why? (That wasn't very helpful was it, Slinky...)

Comment: I would of at least expected a snarky comment asking if I registered the constant UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert

Answer (score 2):

Forgot to register for the alert (standard) push, which is set by adding the constant **UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert];
```

Comment: D'oh, haha glad you were able to find it.